# Cannot get a specific href out of requests

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to capture a unique url using Pythons Requests

Source website is https://www.realestate.com.au/property/1-10-grosvenor-rd-terrigal-nsw-2260

Goal Url is http://www.realestate.com.au/sold/property-unit-nsw-terrigal-124570934

When i tried

```
(Unique_ID,) = (x.text_content() for x in tree.xpath('//a[@class="property-
value__link--muted rui-button-brand property-value__btn-listing"]'))
```

The CSV returned **View Listing**

Unless im mistaken, i've done the correct class search, as the href would not be unique enough? Am i supposed to do something different to capture URL's instead of text?

Full code below if required.

Thanks in advance.

```
import requests
import csv
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import csv
from lxml import html

df = pd.read_excel("C:\Python27\Projects\REA_UNIQUE_ID\\UN.xlsx",             sheetname="UN")
dnc = df['Property']
dnc_list = list(dnc)
url_base = "https://www.realestate.com.au/property/"
URL_LIST = []

for nd in dnc_list:
    nd = nd.strip()
    nd = nd.lower()
    nd = nd.replace(" ", "-")
    URL_LIST.append(url_base + nd)

text2search = '''The information provided'''

with open('Auctions.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    for index, url in enumerate(URL_LIST):
        page = requests.get(url)
        print '\r' 'Scraping URL ' + str(index+1) +   ' of  ' + str(len(URL_LIST)),

        if text2search in page.text:
            tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
            (title,) = (x.text_content() for x in tree.xpath('//title'))
            (Unique_ID,) = (x.text_content() for x in    tree.xpath('//a[@class="property-value__link--muted rui-button-brand property-    value__btn-listing"]'))
            #(sold,) = (x.text_content().strip() for x in     tree.xpath('//p[@class="property-value__agent"]'))
            writer.writerow([title, Unique_ID])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text_content()` allows you to get text only. Try to scrape `@href` as below

```
(Unique_ID,) = (x for x in tree.xpath('//a[@class="property-value__link--muted rui-button-brand property-value__btn-listing"]/@href'))
```